# DY-graph xaxis range labeling

Tags: polymer, dygraphs

I am trying to label xaxis lable range in uniform format. currently I am getting the xaxis labels as below.

But I want this to be represented in format like "20:00 21:00 23:00 '*next day Date*' 01:00 03:00 ..." and so on based on data available.

[image]

Also I want to display mouse over xaxis value in legend. What code change I need to do as part of this change ?

Here is the code snippet

```
new Dygraph(
            this.$.chart,
            data,
            {
                title: this.chartData.response.chartDataSet.xAxisHeading,
        
                labels: data_labels,
                axisLabelWidth: 60,          
                ylabel: this.chartData.response.chartDataSet.yAxisHeading,
                height: 300,
                width: setWidth,
                hideOverlayOnMouseOut: false,
                legend: 'follow',
                fillGraph: true,
                pixelsPerLabel: pixelsPerLabelXaxis,
                legendFormatter: legendFormatter,
                
                axes: {
                    x: {
                        axisLabelFormatter: function(d) {
                             this.value = in_data.chartDataSet.xCoordinates[d];
                            
                            if(this.value!==undefined){
                                if(historicalPeriod === 21 || historicalPeriod === 22 ||  historicalPeriod === 23){
                                    return moment(this.value, 'MM-DD-YYYY_HH:mm:ss').format('DD - MMM');
                                }
                                else if(historicalPeriod === 24){
                                    return moment(this.value, 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('MMM-YYYY');
                                }else{
                                   return moment(this.value, 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm');
                                  
                                }
                            }
                            return in_data.chartDataSet.xCoordinates[d];
                        }                       
                    }
                },
            }
        );
```

Comment: Could you share a more self-contained example, perhaps through dygraphs.com/jsbin?

Comment: @danvk Thanks. I have resolved the issue. My mistake was , I was not passing first parameter as in proper date format.

Comment: @danvk This is not related to this question. But is it possible to draw one more Yaxis on same side (left side), Which is not relevant to graph. I will just pass start and end range and the second Yaxis should show that.